# How to update multiple models at once by an array that include post_id

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have a Model `Post` and there is an array that includes `post_id` like this:

```
hashes = [[post_id: 1, info: 'foo'],
          [post_id: 3, info: 'bar'],
          [post_id: 4, info: 'foobar']]
```

I can update models by this code.

```
hashes.each do |h|
  post = Post.find(h[:post_id])
  next if post.nil?
  post.update(info: h[:info])
end
```

But the array size is normally over 3000, if possible I want to avoid call `update` so many times.
How can I implement this function without using `each` loop?

Comment: Why not use `update_columns`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for [Update records](https://cbabhusal.wordpress.com/2015/01/03/updating-multiple-records-at-the-same-time-rails-activerecord/) - from the documentation Updating multiple records; different col with different data
You can do like this Example:

`people = { 1 => { "first_name" => "David" }, 2 => { "first_name" => "Jeremy" } }
 Person.update(people.keys, people.values)`

Comment: Thanks I think this is the only way to update multiple records, but the SQL commit runs for every model and the speed of the update doesn't change. I gonna stick with ruby `each` method. Because it's more easy to read.

Comment: It's very helpful If you have records like above example.